# PowerShell IIS How to make each recycle period 2 minutes apart

Tags: powershell, iis, pool, application-pool, recycle

I need to set all times for IIS pools to be recycled each 2 minutes apart. I want to create a script in PS that would set that up for me. This is how it looks:"

```
$AppPool = Get-IISAppPool
$AppPoolName = $AppPool | select -ExpandProperty name

foreach ($pool in $AppPoolName) {
#Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\$pool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time -Value 3.00:00:00
}
```

How do I add 2min each time?
-Value 3.00:00:00
-Value 3.00:02:00
-Value 3.00:04:00
etc

Answer (score 1):

The format to use is what a [TimeSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan) object outputs when using `.ToString('c')`.

You can add 2 minutes to a TimeSpan inside the loop like

```
$time = New-TimeSpan -Days 3 -Hours 0 -Minutes 0 -Seconds 0

foreach ($pool in $AppPoolName) {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\$pool -Name recycling.periodicRestart.time -Value $time.ToString('c')
    $time = $time.Add((New-TimeSpan -Minutes 2))
}
```